# How to use a method for filtering generic HashMap - Java

Tags: java, list, lambda, hashmap

Let's consider the following method, that allows me get the items of a generic Map filtering the item that have a geneiric attribute== to a Value (it is not a my code):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Utilities {

    public static <T> List<T> getObjectWithAttributeEqualTo(Map<?, T> MyMap_Arg, Function<T, ?> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg, Object MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg) {
         return  MyMap_Arg.values().stream()
        .filter(o -> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg.apply(o).equals(MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: how to invoke and use this method?

let's say I have a Class called 'Car' with a NOT STATIC method 'getColor()'. I have the object 'myHashMap', that is a map of car, then declared as

```
HashMap<Integer, Car> myHashMap ;
```

I want for example get the list of red cars inside my myHashMap.

Comment: `car` is the name of the parameter of your lambda function. If you are not familiar with lambdas in Java, look them up in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: See the signature of getObjectWithAttributeEqualTo. There you can notice that the second parameter of this method is a Function type. Then, car -> car.getColor() is an instance of Function.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: You should provide the code of the `Car` class. I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine in Eclipse Oxygen, I think your IDE is wrong giving you a 'not static' error:

```
 List<Car> redCars = getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(myHashMap, Car::getColor, "red");
```

Comment: I use Netbeans.

Comment: I just tryed again and I get aways the error: non static method getColor() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

FOUND SOLUTION:

```
List<Car> redCars = Utilities.getObjectWithAttributeEqualTo(myHashMap, object->object.getColor(), "red");
```